# Prevent the line discipline from handling control characters

Tags: linux, terminal, control-characters

When you send a control character from the terminal, for example if you pressed `Ctrl+C`, the *line discipline* will receive the byte representing this control character (which is `0x03` in the case of `Ctrl+C`).

Now instead of the *line discipline* sending the byte `0x03` to the program associated with the terminal, it will instead send it the `SIGINT` signal (or it will do some other action if it is a different control character).

Now is there a way to prevent the *line discipline* from handling control characters, so what I want is for the program associated with the terminal to receive the actual bytes representing the control characters (`0x03` in our case).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On linux, you'd use

```
$ stty intr undef
```

on the terminal concerned. That sets the interrupt character to nothing ("undef"). To restore you would use

```
$ stty intr ^c
```

See `man stty` for details.

Answer (score 1):

> different control character […] control characters

I note the plural.  You are looking for *non-canonical input mode*, known before the POSIX standard as *raw mode*.  This is the mode that applications that use GNU Readline, or ZLE, or libedit employ.  Their code sets it with the `tcgetattr()`, `cfmakeraw()` and `tcsetattr()` library functions, or similar.  These are also the underpinnings of `stty raw`. (Note the existence of `stty sane` if you play with this.)

## Further reading

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/39302351/340790
- [POSIX terminal interface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX_terminal_interface).  Wikipedia.
- [`cfmakeraw()`](http://netbsd.gw.com/cgi-bin/man-cgi?cfmakeraw).  NetBSD Manual pages. 2004.