# How to send the byte representing a control character from the terminal to the application?

Tags: linux, shell, terminal

I have created a command-line application in Linux that reads data from `stdin` (the `stdin` can be the terminal).

When I type `Ctrl+C` on the terminal, the terminal will send the byte `0x03` to the line discipline. Now instead of the line discipline sending the byte `0x03` to my application, it will instead handle `0x03` as a control character and send the `SIGINT` signal to my application.

Is there a way to make sure that the byte `0x03` is sent to my application when I press `Ctrl+C` (without having to change the line discipline settings like mentioned in this [question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/401010/prevent-the-line-discipline-from-handling-control-characters)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>V</kbd> (or whatever `lnext` is set to on the line discipline) will force the next keypress to be input literally.